# Minigame de adivinhação contando errado

Tags: python, python-3.x

Total de acertos e chutes não aparecem corretos, se mudo "acertos" e "totalguess" para 0 o primeiro acerto ou chute conta como 0 e queria como 1

```py
from random import randint
acertos = 1
totalguess = 1
while acertos != 10:
    x = randint(1, 5)
    chute = int(input('Enter your guess'))
    if chute == x:
        print('Congratz! \n' + str(acertos) + ' Hits ')
        totalguess += 1
        acertos += 1
    else:
        print('Not quite! \nTry again! \n' + 'Attempts: ' + str(totalguess))
        totalguess += 1
print('End Game!\n' + 'Hits:' + str(acertos) + '\nAttempts: ' + str(totalguess))
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ggt9.png

Comment: Para resolver o problema não é só inicializar `acertos` e `totalguess` com `0` e atualizar o valor  (`totalguess += 1` e `acertos += 1`) antes de imprimir as mensagens?

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há duas causas para os problemas no seu código:

- O total de acertos está sendo printado antes de ser incrementado;
- As variáveis não estão sendo inicializadas com 0, para ir incrementado quando preciso.

Resolvendo esses problemas, o código fica assim:

```
from random import randint

acertos = 0
totalguess = 0

while acertos < 10:
    x = randint(1, 5)
    chute = int(input('Enter your guess: '))

    if chute == x:
        acertos += 1
        totalguess += 1

        print('Congratz! \n' + str(acertos) + ' Hits ')


    else:
        print('Not quite! \nTry again! \n' + 'Attempts: ' + str(totalguess))
        totalguess += 1

print('End Game!\n' + 'Hits:' + str(acertos) + '\nAttempts: ' + str(totalguess))
```

E passa a funcionar corretamente.

Comment: shoow, muito obrigado mano, não estou acreditando que o meu problema era tão obvio assim kkkk